# Magento rule_coupons.type column missing in 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have an upgraded shop from 1.6 to 1.7.  When I go to try to use a coupon on the front end I get a debug email with the following information.  This didnt happen when it was at 1.6.  Just now after upgrade.

Has anyone seen this issue thus far?

URL: http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/checkout/cart/couponPost/
IP Address: 
Time: 2012-10-09 08:04:26 GMT
Error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rule_coupons.type' in 'where clause'

Trace:

```
#0 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/hsstore/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(268): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/community/TBT/Rewards/Model/Salesrule/Observer.php(167): Varien_Data_Collection->getFirstItem()
#11 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): TBT_Rewards_Model_Salesrule_Observer->checkRedemptionCouponBefore(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(TBT_Rewards_Model_Salesrule_Observer), 'checkRedemption...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(532): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#17 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('couponPost')
#18 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/hsstore/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/hsstore/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Comment: maybe should be moved to http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm getting the same error. sporadically. re-caching and re-indexing helps temporarily.